# Multiprocessing pipeline with Kafka+Airflow+Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, apache-kafka, multiprocessing, airflow

I have a simple python pipeline that crawls a property page for data, the data on the page is divided into states and what type of property. The steps of the pipeline are as follow:

- A loop over all combinations of state and property type
- For each combination, a crawler goes through the corresponding page and collects the URLs of all properties
- For each property, data is crawled, cleaned and enriched before being stored in a SQLite DB

Currently this is a single-threaded and very simple process. I want to improve this and I am looking for modern tools to use in my new pipeline. Both to visualize the status of the processing and run it as a multiprocessing pipeline.

Currently I have a first idea of using Kafka and Airflow. One process crawls a page for property URLs, and creates Kafka messages for each URL. A second process then takes a single Kafka message and processes it; crawl, clean, enrich, store. Meanwhile in Airflow I can have a nice overview of the status of processes and even retry failed ones. There each combination of state and property type is split into separate DAGs.

The issue is however that crawling is not something I can do with multiprocessing, as that will cause too many request to the target page and calls will become blocked eventually. The pipeline will fail.

My new idea is to also include Kubernetes. I will have one pod that does the crawling of property URLs. Then a second pod will crawl one property URL at a time. The final pod would be responsible for processing the property data (clean,enrich,store), but this pod I want to have X instances of because crawling the data will be faster than processing it.

Because there is a lot of data crawled for each property (around 20 fields, at least one contains a long description of the property), I do not think Kafka is a good option to transfer information between the pods. But I see no other option to include a work queue. The only option I could think of was that messages always only include the URL of a listing. But after crawling, data is stored in SQLite, and the final pod that will clean and enrich the data, will instead need to pull the data from the SQLite DB. Is that a reasonable idea, or are there better options?

I have tried to google for tutorials and suggestions on how to setup a system with `Kubernetes+Airflow+Kafka`, but I find nothing. Some pages are specifically only about running Airflow withing Kubernetes, but there is never information about Kafka. Does this mean the combination is not possible, and if so, why not? Also do you have suggestions for better tools or complete systems that I should look into instead?

Apologies if my question is too vague or open, I could not find other places where I could find suggestions for building up this pipeline in the best way possible and give me skills to find a job.

Comment: What does "improve" mean in this context? It sounds overly complicated. What is wrong with the single-threaded process?

Comment: Look at temporal.io open source project. It would replace both Kafka and Airflow in your application.

Comment: @RolandSmith single-threaded it takes >3 days, and I want to learn something new to put on my CV for job searches

Comment: @MaximFateev thank you I will have a look at temporal.io

Comment: I didn't know about temporal.io, it looks great, is it something similar to [GCP Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows)? That's what I thought after looking at the main page. I'll know more soon, I've just signed up for the workshop on 26 October.

Comment: It is different from GCP Workflows in that it uses general-purpose language code to specify workflows instead of JSON/YAML.

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily want to deploy Kafka on K8s you can use https://strimzi.io/ which is a mature open source [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) allowing to deploy Kafka in Kubernetes quite easily.

However, I think you can implement what you want to achieve with some simple cloud serverless features, in GCP you can [use pubsub + Cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).

There are equivalent services in other public clouds.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into strimzi, it looks promizing. But no I do not specifically need Kafka, any other MQ would suffice, or way to implement a task queue into the pipeline.

I have thought of cloud solutions, but since I do not have money to spend on the costs,  and I feel I will have a lot of trial and error to get it running, which will also increase the processing costs.  I think at first I want to focus on self-hosted solutions, that could be also transferred to something I can do at a company (who hasn't decided to move to the cloud yet)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why the runtime of a program is so long, you need to *profile* it.

Start with profiling the current single-threaded implementation using the `cProfile` module from the standard library.
Try:

```
python -m cProfile -s cumtime yourscript.py <arguments>
```

This will give you an idea where your program is spending its time.

I cannot stress enough how important this is!
Sometimes the bottlenecks are totally not what you think they are.

For example, in one of my programs it turned out that it spent most of its time in *string formatting*!
And by experimenting I found out that I could *halve* that time by using the appropriate *type speficier*:

```
In [1]: f = 139.3592529296875;

In [3]: %timeit str(f)
724 ns ± 0.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit "{0}".format(f)
734 ns ± 1.21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit "{0:.5f}".format(f)
314 ns ± 0.0365 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit "{0:f}".format(f)
313 ns ± 7.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit "{0:e}".format(f)
382 ns ± 0.171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Only after you have profiled your script can you think about improvements.
Generally, I would advise to start with whatever code takes longest (but *not* built-ins; not much you can do about those).

Keep in mind that the largest improvement often comes from a better algorithm.

Later in the development of the same program, I converted the numerical data to strings once before building the strings, saving a lot of duplicated effort because all the numbers were used multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, I have actually already run a profiling of the single-threaded code using cProfile + snakeviz for visualizing it, and it was clear that the cleaning process takes an equal amount of time, so it would benefit from multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is for scheduling programs, maybe within Kubernetes pods, but not needed; you could run a standalone Airflow worker cluster.

Regarding Kafka, Airflow isn't really needed for consuming since Kafka topics are endless and continuous. You could publish a url to a multi partitioned Kafka topic, then run as many consumers (threads or processes) as partitions, then you have your parallel processing. Since processing is in parallel, don't use sqlite, since that would require only one instance consuming all data.

You can still use Kubernetes to do that processing with Knative or OpenFaaS, instead, for example.

You could also use NATS or RabbitMQ since you just need a Queue. Or Celery and Redis are commonly used with Python.

Comment: I am not fully sure I understood. Is your suggestion to setup a standalone Airflow worker cluster instead of Kubernetes+Airflow?

I am including airflow to keep track of when a task (specific combination of state and property type) was last run, as I run it only on a monthly basis, not continuous. It is more of a nice to have, especially the GUI it comes with.

Knative look interesting. That could also replace Airflow as scheduler, right? Does it handle large information passed between pods?

I thought that NATS and RabbitMQ would have same issue with large messages?

Comment: Any database can keep track of state. Airflow can schedule Linux processes. You don't seem to have a specific need for containers or managing a k8s cluster, even if it's scaled down.  It's a stateless monthly process job, you really only need a lambda/serverless function. Unclear how large you're referring to. Data under 1MB per event should be fine, by default, and you can use binary formats+compression to reduce data volumes

Comment: Sorry I was not clear with what I meant with"state", I meant geographical state, as in Alabama, Texas etc :) No there is not a specific need for containers, but this is a hobby project mainly to learn new tools that I can use for job searching. Kubernetes is quite hot right now, so I tried to focus toward that. I do not think it would exceed 1 mb, then I will stick with Kafka. I would think that Kafka+Kubernetes+Airflow would be useful tools to know when applying for jobs?